# cast string into sql query

Tags: c#, mysql, string, casting

I have a method that receives four strings and is supposed to insert them into my database table.
Unfortunately the table only receives the values “nameIncoming', 'versionIncoming', 'publisherIncoming', 'installDateIncoming” and not the content of the strings.

```
//Insert statement
        public void Insert(string nameIncoming, string versionIncoming, string publisherIncoming, string installDateIncoming)
        {
           string query = "insert into Michael_Workstation(name, version, publisher, installDate) values('nameIncoming', 'versionIncoming', 'publisherIncoming', 'installDateIncoming')";

       ....

        }
```

I think I need to cast the string somehow. I already tried different things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You are posting the variable names as strings instead of variables.

Comment: You only need to concatenate the strings but I would advice against that practice and use parametrized queries instead

Comment: You're not using your variables. You've hard-coded in literal values instead. But you'd be doing the wrong thing anyway by concatenating your SQL (Google *Little Bobby Tables*). Search this site for *C# parameterized queries* to learn the proper way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: You do not even need that method as there is no *safe* preparation step to convert that into a usable query.  Parameters are made for taking your values and passing them to the database.  Among other things your have vars which appear tobe dates which are being handled as strings; SQL parameters preserve the data type

Comment: Thanks for ure advise, I will read up on C# parameterized queries and learn how to do it the proper way.

Comment: some people recommended me to use a entity framework. what do you guys think about that tip?

Answer (score 1):

You've explicitly set the values of those columns to the names of your variables, rather than setting the values of those variables.

Any text inside the single quotes in `values('nameIncoming', 'versionIncoming', 'publisherIncoming', 'installDateIncoming')";` is being seen as a value and not a variable.

In this situation, it would probably be better to use parameterized values for the query. This ensures that you are setting a variable's value directly to the named column.

For MySQL, it would look like this:

```
MySqlCommand insertSQL = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Michael_Workstation(name, version, publisher, installDate) VALUES (@name, @version, @publisher, @installDate)";
```

Then, to set the value of a column, you would add each like so:

```
insertSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameIncoming);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query C#:

```
string query = "insert into Michael_Workstation(name, version, publisher, installDate) values('" + nameIncoming + "', '" + versionIncoming + "','" + publisherIncoming + "', '" + installDateIncoming + "')";
```

Comment: This has never ever been the correct way to compose SQL queries in NET.  It is not only error prone but very dangerous.  Sadly, it is the kind of answer which is becoming all too common on this site.